# Finding the application name in GWT

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am successfully deploying a GWT app to Google App Engine.  However, I need to set up a second test instance on the app engine, and I need certain constants to change in that second instance.

Is there a call I can make to find out what the application name is, which would let me change the constants?

It's very important that the second instance not have the same constants as the first instance, so a process of manually changing constants doesn't work too well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java the app ID can apparently be retrieved with this call:

```
ApiProxy.Environment.getAppId()
```

[More on Application Identity](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/functions?csw=1#get_application_id)

Comment: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAppId() gives me the result with an "s~" in front of it, which is pretty good.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

figured out my own problem.

Call this:

```
com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty.applicationId.get()
```